# Did Jack Malik try to slip one of his own songs into the release?

Tags: yesterday

In a recording studio scene, one of the songs prepared by Jack Malik is rejected. His agent describes the song as making her bored and indifferent, and the song is dropped.

Was it a Beatles song that was rejected, or did Malik try to slip in one of his own songs?

Comment: Do you have a timestamp from the full movie, or Youtube extract?

Comment: "His agent describes the song as making her bored and indifferent" neither of those words turned up in a subtitle file I found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Summer Song" isn't a Beatles song. It's credited to Richard Curtis, Adem Ilhan and Daniel Pemberton; performed, of course, by Himesh Patel.

He sings it several times through the movie, it's even in the opening credits as he busks in various locations around the town  - it's the only vaguely half-decent original song he does [presumably quite intentionally on the part of the writers] and the only original composition he tries to record. [Timestamp approx 51:25 in the movie].
It is, of course, rejected.

It's described in the studio scene…

> That is… it's simple without being charming.
> I'm struggling to find the words.
> I hated it,
> but I wasn't interested in it enough to listen to it again to find out why.

[image]

Comment: I don't know the song you refer to, but Summer Song is blatantly pants; & I'm pretty certain it's designed to be that bad. If you set up 15 Beatles hits on a single album, the bar is somewhat higher than usual. The film's audience expects it to be this way, too, so it's simply a plot point to reinforce that fore-knowledge.